# Strategy for reducing CNF-SAT to this problem

Tags: algorithm, np, reduction, np-complete, np-hard

Suppose there is a satisfiability problem (call it oscillating-CNF) where the input is a list of CNF clauses and we want to show that this problem is indeed NP-complete (by reducing CNF-SAT to oscillating-CNF). A satisfied oscillating-CNF instance is when each even indexed clause (0-2-4) is true and each uneven indexed clause is false (1-3-5...).

My question is this, is it a feasible strategy to:

1. Chose a random variable from the CNF (call it R1)
2. Negate the CNF expression
3. Convert the negated expression in step 2 back to CNF format
4. Create a list and in every even index place (R1 || !R1), and in the odd index place the clauses from step 3.
5. use this list as input to the oscillating-CNF problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, when you negate a disjunctive clause it becomes a conjunction. I would keep the original problem in the even clauses, and introduce auxiliary variables for the odd clauses (making them trivially dissatisfiable without containing the original variables).

Comment: That is true. We essentially get a DNF and it is known that turning a DNF into a CNF in polynomial time is possible. I dont doubt there is a "smarter" or more efficient reduction im just curious if this strategy is not feasible at all. Thank you for the response!

Comment: It’s not a feasible strategy. Consider the SAT `A * !A`. Its negation is `!(A * !A) = (!A + A)`, which is your one-clause reduction, and which is satisfiable even though the input wasn’t.